# Spring boot maven plugin jvmArguments not being set

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

On Intellij Idea:

When I set `-Duser.language=tr` via maven run configuration, language is set, but when I set it via pom.xml as below it is not set.

```
    <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
               <jvmArguments>
                     -Duser.language=tr
               </jvmArguments>
          </configuration>
          ...
    </plugin>
```

Comment: According to spring boot doc, looks like this jvmArguments setting is only available in case you are using mvn-springboot:run command. In intel ij, it would directly run the main class (annotated with @SpringBootApplication) instead of the mvn command.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run

Comment: That seems to be true but I need to be work via jus pom.xml. Thanks. I will post another topic

Comment: @HưngChu Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71911915/setting-vm-argument-via-pom-xml