# Setting VM argument via pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, jvm-arguments

I need to set `-Duser.language` via `pom.xml` since I need language specific database queries.
When I pass `-Duser.language=tr` to VM options upon running spring boot application on Intellij, it works. But I need this to be done in `pom.xml` for profiling.

Below ways are not working. Language is not set.

```
  <profile>
      <properties>
            <argLine>-Duser.language=tr -Duser.region=TR</argLine>
      </properties>
  ...
  </profile>
```

---

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
           <source>${java.version}</source>
           <target>${java.version}</target>
           <verbose>true</verbose>
           <fork>true</fork>
           <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-J-Duser.language=tr_TR</arg>
           </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

---

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.22.2</version>
     <configuration>
          <argLine>-Duser.language=tr -Duser.region=TR</argLine>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
                 <user.language>tr</user.language>
                 <user.region>TR</user.region>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

---

Only this is working but I need to run application with `mvn spring-boot:run` for this to work and that is not an option.

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
            <jvmArguments>
                -Duser.language=tr
            </jvmArguments>
      </configuration>
      ...
 </plugin>
```

How can I pass vm arguments via pom.xml?

Comment: Maybe xy-problem. Why do you need the queries in a specific language?

Comment: Sorting fails for Turkish characters when querying. For example; Turkish character "Ç" comes after "C" but if language is not set, it places "Ç" to the end of the list when ordering.

Comment: Hm, ordering is done on the sql-server. Try this instead in the SQL: `ORDER BY fieldname COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci`

Comment: I can not use native query. It needs to be done in jpql via Spring Data.